# Can we add 2 images of different frame size on 1 UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my requirement is like i have to add 2 images, so for that one can i use single UIImageView or i have to go for 2 different UIImageViews

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add two images the the `UIImageView` class. However create a custom `UIView` with two `UIImageView`'s and add the images to the view.

This way you will have a custom class specific to your current requirement and you can use it across your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

A standard uiImageView only has one UIImage variable.

Either make a custom UIImageView, or use two views.